# Why does renaming my variable prevent a segfault?

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, iteration

I have a single depth-first search algorithm implemented to traverse my graph, given the iterator to a starting node.

Documentation summary:

- `GraphIter` is a **typedef** for `Graph::iterator`
- `Graph` class **extends** `map<string, Node>`
- `start->second.edges()` returns `set<string>`

This code causes a segmentation fault if the **size** of `start->second.edges()` is **0**:

(I've truncated the irrelevant pieces, including the recursive calls, for brevity.)

---

### Bad Code

```
void Graph::dfs(GraphIter start)
{
    cout << "EDGES SIZE: " << start->second.edges().size() << endl;

    for (set<string>::iterator it = start->second.edges().begin();
          it != start->second.edges().end(); ++it)
    {
        GraphIter iter = this->find(*it);     // <--- SEGMENTATION FAULT
    }
}
```

---

Now watch what happens when I pull `start->second.edges()` into a local variable: no more segfault!

Here's the code that doesn't generate a segfault:

---

### Good Code

```
void Graph::dfs(GraphIter start)
{
    set<string> edges = start->second.edges();       // <--- MAGIC TRICK
    cout << "EDGES SIZE: " << edges.size() << endl;

    for (set<string>::iterator it = edges.begin();
          it != edges.end(); ++it)
    {
        GraphIter iter = this->find(*it);
    }
}
```

---

So the difference is that in the good code, when the **size** of the set of strings (from the `edges()` method) is **0**, the `for` loop is never entered in the second case. But in the first case, the `for` loop is still executed at least once until it realize that it can't dereference the `it` variable.

Why are these different? Don't they access the same parts of memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `edges()` returns a `set` by value, `start->second.edges().begin()` and `start->second.edges().end()` return iterators to different containers because each call to `edges()` results in a new `set` being returned.

By creating a single copy with a named variable you ensure that the iterators all come from the same container and you can validly iterator from `begin()` to `end()`.

Comment: That's why! Thanks. I wasn't considering that while the iterator is a pointer, the `edges()` method, called subsequently, is returning by value, not by reference.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that `start->second.edges()` returns an `std::set<std::string>` by value. That would render the iterators in the loop incompatible and lead to undefined behaviour.

Your "magic trick"

```
set<string> edges = start->second.edges();
```

ensures that you are iterating over the same container, "edges".

You could fix it by having `Node::edges()` return by reference:

```
const std::set<std::string>& edges() const { .... }
```

Comment: ... And change `iterator` to `const_iterator`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey ...or just use `auto it = ...` :)